# Using a for loop to create nested list from large database

Tags: r

I'm working with a large database of survey data (182545 observations of 34 variables at monthly frequency from 2003 to 2019). There's anywhere from 800 to 1300 respondents per month. My end goal is to summarise the responses to  each each question (% positive, % neutral, % negative) for each month, but I'm finding the first step of separating out the data by month problematic.

After loading in the data, I created a nested list which contains list the length of each month's respondents by using a value that signifies the year and the month. This worked as expected, but I can't seem to populate each month's list with the actual data and am struggling to figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
# extract yearmo unique values

yearmo <- unique(esm$yearmo)

# create main nested list

nest <- as.list(rep("", length(yearmo))) # main nest for 195 months

for(i in 1:length(yearmo)){
  nest[[i]] <- as.list(rep("", length(which(esm$yearmo==yearmo[[i]]))))

}


for(k in 1:(length(nest[[j]][k])-1)){
  for(j in 1:(length(nest[[j]]-1))){
    nest[[j]][k] <- esm[which(esm$yearmo == yearmo[[j]]), ]
  }
}
```

The error I get is: Error in nest[[j]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: I bet it's this: Your parentheses are different for `1:(length(nest[[j]][k])-1)` and `(length(nest[[j]]-1))`. Notice the difference between `1:3-1` and `1:(3-1)`

Comment: It's hard to help you if we can't reproduce your problem. Can you [edit] your question with a [mcve] of your problem, including a toy dataset and desired results? You can use `dput` to export a representative part of your dataset in a format you can paste into the question, or make an example using a preinstalled dataset

Comment: Another way to approach this problem is using the `group_by` and `summarize` functions from the dplyr package.

Comment: The real answer is don't do this.  Use `dplyr`, e.g.: `esm %>% group_by(respondant,yearmo) %>% summarize( <whatever you want> )`

Comment: Thanks thc and Dave2e, your suggestion worked!